# Python Selenium 4 - Firefox installAddon not working

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I've upgraded to selenium 4

```
new_addon_path = 'D:/GOOD/Coding/uBlock.xpi'
browser1 = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(options=opts, etc....)
browser1.install_addon(new_addon_path)
```

**Error:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Expected absolute path: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520001 (NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH) .....
```

**Documentation:**

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/CHANGES.md

The documentation says:

> Changes to firefox.Driver .. Added installAddon(path)

A **temporary profile** automatically is created in `C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/`
I want this temporary profile, so that I can thread multiple driver sessions at once without creating and assigning new profiles manually.

This temp profile can be found using `browser1.__dict__['capabilities']['moz:profile']`

**Fixes I have tried:**

tried placing `uBlock.xpi` into profile folder, then calling `browser1.install_addon(path to profile/extensions/uBlock.xpi)`

tried placing `uBlock.xpi` in same folder as `geckodriver.log`

All paths fail, regardless of if they are relative or apsolute paths.

**Documentation also says:**

> Changes to firefox.Options .. Added addExtensions

which does not even exist as an option in `firefox.Options`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lads at github.com solved the issue,

`browser1.install_addon('D:/GOOD/Coding/uBlock.xpi')`

should look like:

`browser1.install_addon(r'D:\GOOD\Coding\uBlock.xpi')`

This works

I'm not sure why, since the `service()` function or any other **python selenium** functions works perfectly fine on **windows** with blackslashes. This path however requires this formula.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph -- the service path is handled by the Selenium code, whereas the addon path is passed to geckodriver which may handle paths differently.

Answer (score 2):

> `Message: Expected absolute path`

This error message tells you the exact problem.

`install_addon()` requires an **absolute path**, but you are passing it a **relative path**.

The solution is to use an absolute path.

> The documentation says

The documentation you pointed to is for the JavaScript bindings, but your code is using the Python bindings. You are reading the wrong documentation.

Comment: its the only documentation regarding the most recent version of selenium. And I am using the full path ... as i mentioned near the end of the post. The path i'm using is: `D:/Coding/Selenium_Test/firefox/firefox_exe/uBlock.xpi` ... is that not an absolute path?

Comment: your example code clearly shows you are using a relative path, not the one from your comment.  Why would you post an example that is supposed to fail and then claim in comments that you are not actually running that code?

Comment: yes but the function `install_addon()` is offered for selection in python ... only the function has no use because it appears to be broken. I have submitted it to `https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues` ... there is also no other function that provides what it provides without setting a predetermined profile

Comment: selenium 4 gecko driver updates also suggest they are enabling more opportunities to avoid mandatory profile assignment. Which is why I was hoping `install_addon()` would work